# webpage collapses when minimizing html & css

Tags: html, css

My body div collapses under the left bar navigation when i begin to minimize the window.

Can somebody please advise on what i have done wrong or what more i need to do.

Much appreciated, thank you.

css snippet:

```
#navigation {


   float: left;
   min-width: 20%;
   margin: 0;
   margin-top: 5px;
   font-weight: normal;

}

#centerDoc {

   float: left;
   width: 80%;
   padding: 0 0 20px 0; /*top right bottom left*/
   margin-top: 0px;

}


#header{

   position: relative;  
   width:100%;
   height:96px;
   margin-left: 5px;


}



#footer {
        font-family: Trebuchet MS;
        font-size: x-small;
        padding:2px;
        margin:0px;
        background-color:#CBE3F6;
        color:#fff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #9EC4E2;
        border-top: 1px solid #9EC4E2;
        text-align:center;

        width: 100%;
        }


 #wrapper{


   position: relative;
   margin-left: 5px;


}



#container {
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

Template of a page:

```
<?php require_once 'includes/header.php';?>


<div id="wrapper">

    <?php require_once 'includes/nav.php'; ?>


    <div id="centerDoc">







</div>  <!--centerDoc !-->
 </div> <!-- wrapper !-->



   </div> <!--container !-->




</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float` attribute from `#centerDoc`, and add `margin-left: 20%.` to it

Then change `min-width: 20%` in `#navigation` to `width: 20%` or `max-width: 20%`. Without this the text inside `centerDoc` flows under the `#navigation`.

You might want to keep your measurement synchronized. You have `width: 80%` in `#centerDoc` and `min-width` in `#navigation`. It might be easier to picture the layout if you'd used plain `width` in both occasions and assigned the `min/max-width` attributes to the `body` of the page (so the widths of the `#navigation` and `#centerDoc` are relative to the common parent of them).

---

Edit: CSS:

```
#navigation {
  float: left;
  width:20%;
}
#centerDoc {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left:20%;
}
#header{
  width:100%;
  height:96px;
}
#container { 
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-width: 600px;
}
```

Removed the `#wrapper`. See the `max-/min-width´ in the`#container`. The scrollbars appear into the browser when the page is less then 600 pixels wide. The page also doesn't become wider then 1200 px. This allows you to define the`width`s of the`#navigation`and`#centerDoc` as percentages.

With the following HTML everything should work properly. (Althought I don't know what's inside `nav.php`. Hopefully nothing that clears the floating of the `#navigation`)

```
<div id="container">
  <?php //require_once 'includes/header.php';?>

<div id="navigation">
  <?php //require_once 'includes/nav.php'; ?>
  <p>Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.</p>
</div>  <!--navigation !-->

<div id="centerDoc">
  <p>Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.</p>
</div>  <!--centerDoc !-->
</div> <!--container !-->
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that. i've just stripped everything out and i'm trying the following but now my `#centerDoc` starts under `#navigation` is there a particular reason for this? Here's what i'm trying now:                                                    `#navigation {


   
   float: left;
   max-width:100px;
  


}

#centerDoc {
   width: 800px;


}


#header{

 
   width:900px;
   height:96px;

   
  
}



 #wrapper{
 
 width:900px;

}



#container {
   width: 900px;
  
}
`

Comment: @greenhoodlum The code above should work correctly. Do you have a clearfloat somewhere in the `#navigation` or above the `#centerDoc`?

Comment: nope never used it but i did manage to fix it :) i was told its better using % instead of pixels to match any screen - is this true?

Comment: @greenhoodlum Using percentages is a better choice if you want the page to resize when resizing the browser window. (Otherwise the page is always X pixels wide.) It's a good idea to define `max-` and `min-width`s as pixels to the `#container` and plain `width`s as percentages to the `#navigation` and `#centerDoc`. (Also add a `margin-left` to the `#centerDoc`. I'll update my answer in a minute...)

Answer (score 0):

I would change min-width in #navigation to max-width. 
That way we make sure that the left navigation bar has not more than the 20% of the width of the page.

Edit:

```
#navigation {
   float: left;
   width: 20%;
   margin: 0;
   margin-top: 5px;
   font-weight: normal;
}

#centerDoc {
   float: right;
   width: 80%;
   padding: 0 0 20px 0; /*top right bottom left*/
   margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: and have you tried changing the "float: left" to "float:right" on #centerDoc ?